# How can I access source_range from timeline object using pyaaf?

Tags: python, timeline

I have figured out using `opentimelineio` I can get `source_range`

```
timeline = otio.adapters.read_from_file(<some_aaf_file>)
for clip in timeline.each_clip():
     print clip.name,  clip.source_range
```

How can I achieve the same using `pyaaf`, I tried hard to access the timeline object the only all keys I get is

```
[u'Origin', u'MarkOut', u'MarkIn', u'UserPos', u'EditRate', 
 u'TimelineMobAttributeList', u'SlotID', u'SlotName',
 u'PhysicalTrackNumber', u'Segment', u'Generation', u'ObjClass']
```

Where can I find `Source_range` of `aaf` file cut data

Comment: Did you try checking in source mob ?